# using google maps or navigation through Intent

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an App in which I am launching  an Intent to use the Google maps navigation.
Now my question is , do I have to include Google maps API Key or some other kind of permission from Google in my App or am I good to go?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `ACTION_VIEW` with a `geo:` `Uri` to start up Google Maps, you do not need a Maps API key or any other kind of permission.